# React + Typescript: props from `cloneElement` only

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component `<MyComponent>` that takes props of type `Props`:

```
interface Props {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    greeting: () => string;
}

export const MyComponent = ({ name, age, greeting }: Props): ReactElement => {
   ...
}
```

However, `MyComponent` is always a child of `WrapperComponent`, which is where `greeting` is passed in:

```
export const WrapperComponent = ({children}) => {
    const thisGreeting = (): void => { console.log('Hello!'); }
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            {
                Children.map((child) => cloneElement(child, {greeting: thisGreeting}))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm currently composing `WrapperComponent` and `MyComponent` like this:

```
<WrapperComponent>
    <MyComponent 
        name="me"
        age={99}
    />
</WrapperComponent>
```

This throws an error, because `MyComponent` is missing `greeting`, but I know that it'll be there eventually. `greeting` is dependent on the specific instance of `WrapperComponent`, which is why it's set up this way.

1. This feels like a bit of an anti-pattern, since `MyComponent` can't (currently) be used outside `WrapperComponent` - is there a better way?
2. If not (anti-pattern and/or a better way) is there a way to convince typescript that `greeting` will get there eventually?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the greeting prop as optional in the Props interface. And set a default arg value for it.

````
interface Props {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    greeting?: () => string;
}

export const MyComponent = ({ name, age, greeting = () => "" }: Props): ReactElement => {
   ...
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

`// @ts-expect-error` is cleaner IMO

… or if you feel this is too loose, then try:

```
<WrapperComponent>
    <MyComponent 
        name = { undefined as unknown as string }
        age  = { undefined as unknown as number }
    />
</WrapperComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as you are envisioning it, there is no way to communicate types between nested components because in JSX the `Component` types are independent of any parent types. You can only type the `children` of the `WrapperComponent` not the `MyComponent` itself.

If you really want to use the jsx syntax to declare the nested child and you don't care too much about the loose typing, I would go with [@Marcus Junius Brutus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274677/marcus-junius-brutus)'s answer using `// @ts-expect-error` but watch out for this since doing so would not show type errors in the entire line.

---

### Alternate approaches

#### Option 1

The first alternate approach here would be what [react suggests](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#passing-data-with-a-render-prop) in favor of using the `cloneElement`, which is to use render props.

> Note: Using the ***uncommon*** `cloneElement` API is discouraged by react.
>
> [image]

So your `MyComponent` would stay the same as you have but your `WrapperComponent` would look something like...

```
export const WrapperComponent = ({
  children: ChildComponent
}: {
  children: (childProps: Pick<Props, "greeting">) => ReactNode;
}) => {
  const thisGreeting = (): string => {
    return "My Greeting";
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">{ChildComponent({ greeting: thisGreeting })}</div>
  );
};
```

> Note the `children` prop type is a function that passes in the `greeting` from the parent component.

The final usage of this would then be...

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <WrapperComponent>
      {({ greeting }) => {
        return <MyComponent name="me" age={99} greeting={greeting} />;
      }}
    </WrapperComponent>
  );
}
```

> Notice that as mentioned above, the `MyComponent` types are still independent but now you have access to the `greeting` value to pass to `MyComponent` directly.

I'd say this is the best approach for your case, unless you really like the simplicity of your approach. But that approach either hides types or logic where other people reading this code may be confused where `greeting` is coming from, this approach makes that explicit.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-glitter-ry7l7w?file=/src/App.tsx

#### Option 2

An alternate approach to achieve better type safety would be to alter the `MyComponent` types, this may not be desirable in the greater context of your app in which case just ignore this option.

This option expects some `ComponentType` that has a `greeting` prop to be passed as a child. To do this we need to refactor the `MyComponent` to something like...

```
export const MyComponent = ({ name, age }: Omit<Props, "greeting">) => ({
  greeting
}: Pick<Props, "greeting">): ReactElement => {
  return <div>MyComponent</div>;
};
```

Then the `WrapperComponent` would be something like...

```
export const WrapperComponent = <
  C extends ComponentType<Pick<Props, "greeting">>
>({
  children: ChildComponent
}: {
  children: ComponentType<Pick<ComponentProps<C>, "greeting">>;
}) => {
  const thisGreeting = (): string => {
    return "My Greeting";
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <ChildComponent greeting={thisGreeting} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

> Notice how we now call the `ChildComponent` directly instead of using the ***uncommon*** `cloneElement` API.

Using this would look like...

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <WrapperComponent>
      {MyComponent({ name: "me", age: 99 })}
    </WrapperComponent>
  );
}
```

> Note: This would change how you'd use `MyComponent` everywhere in your app too, which may not be ideal.
>
> ```
> return (
>   <div>
>     {MyComponent({ name: "me", age: 99 })({ greeting: 'hey' })}
>   </div>
> )
> ```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-sun-cj9vxm?file=/src/App.tsx